# Concatenate Rows from dataset on R, doing group by another column

Tags: r, loops, dataset

I have a dataset with this format:

[image]

And i need to convert on:

[image]

Can i do it without loops?

EDIT:

Hi, thanks again @guscht, im trying to use your example, but im having some of problems, i need use it on PowerBI, with my dataset.

Im trying with

```
library(data.table)

hec1 <- as.data.table(dataset)
res <- hec1[,strsplit(observaciones, split = ";"),by = c("albaran", "fecha", "cliente", "estado", "descrip", "destinatario", "direccion", "cp", "poblacion")]
res[, tipo_pedido := substring(observaciones, 1, regexpr(":", observaciones)-2)][, entregas := substring(observaciones, regexpr(":", observaciones)+2, nchar(observaciones))]
res$V1 <- NULL
res <- res[,strsplit(entregas, split = ","),by = c("albaran", "fecha", "cliente", "estado", "descrip", "destinatario", "direccion", "cp", "poblacion", "tipo_pedido")]
setnames(res, "tipo_pedido", "entregas")
res
```

But it doesn't work, show me this error:

```
Error in strsplit(observaciones, split = ";") : 
  argumento de tipo no-carácter
Calls: [ -> [.data.table -> strsplit
Ejecución interrumpida
```

I think... may can be the problem the origin format?, its a datatable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `data.table`-package you can do the following:

```
dt <- fread(input = '
16/04/2018 23:18|Estrella Disney|1|sandy crespo
16/04/2018 23:18|Estrella Disney|2|sandy crespo
16/04/2018 23:18|Estrella Disney|3|sandy crespo
16/04/2018 23:18|Estrella Disney|4|sandy crespo
16/04/2018 23:18|Estrella Disney|5|sandy crespo
16/04/2018 23:18|Estrella Disney|6|sandy crespo
16/04/2018 23:18|Colleccion|20|sandy crespo
16/04/2018 23:18|Colleccion|4|sandy crespo
', sep = '|')
setnames(dt, c('date_time', 'something', 'number', 'user'))

res <- dt[, paste(number, collapse = ", "), by = c("something", "user", "date_time")][, paste(something, ":", V1, collapse = "; "), by = c("user", "date_time")]
res <- res[, c('date_time', 'V1', 'user'), with = F]
res
          date_time                                                 V1         user
1: 16/04/2018 23:18 Estrella Disney : 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6; Colleccion : 20, 4 sandy crespo
```

In essence this approach uses two `collapse`-statements to generate the column that you want to have. The first one generates the concatenated numbers, the second one generates the variables with the concatenated numbers. The `by`-statements just specify which columns not to modify and to keep.

EDIT: I changed above code to add a `:` between the `something` and the numbers.
To reverse the process you can do something like:

```
res <- res[,strsplit(V1, split = ";"),by = c("user","date_time")]
res[, something := substring(V1, 1, regexpr(":", V1)-2)][, number := substring(V1, regexpr(":", V1)+2, nchar(V1))]
res$V1 <- NULL
res <- res[,strsplit(number, split = ","),by = c("user","date_time","something")]
setnames(res, "V1", "number")
res
           user        date_time       something number
1: sandy crespo 16/04/2018 23:18 Estrella Disney      1
2: sandy crespo 16/04/2018 23:18 Estrella Disney      2
3: sandy crespo 16/04/2018 23:18 Estrella Disney      3
4: sandy crespo 16/04/2018 23:18 Estrella Disney      4
5: sandy crespo 16/04/2018 23:18 Estrella Disney      5
6: sandy crespo 16/04/2018 23:18 Estrella Disney      6
7: sandy crespo 16/04/2018 23:18      Colleccion     20
8: sandy crespo 16/04/2018 23:18      Colleccion      4
```

Comment: Wow, thank  you very much, it was very usefull for me, im a noob on R... If    i need do the reverse process, ¿Its posible  whit something like an split?
Thank you again for your time, 
Regards

Comment: @IsmaelValle Adjusted the answer above.

Comment: Hi, thanks again, im trying to use your example, but im having some of problems, i need use it on PowerBI, with my dataset.

Comment: @IsmaelValle, I don't know PowerBI. Please open a new question for that.